# handling system(command) call timeout in Linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals, fork

I am trying to execute a command (fetching a key from a remote server) using linux's system(cmd). My issue is when the remote server is unreachable, for few IPs it simply waits and do not return, which in turn makes "system()" hang forever. I want to handle this scenario. I am thinking of a way to make my system() waits for a certain duration and if the command do not return, then system() command must come out reporting an unsuccessful status.

My command looks something like this:

```
int status = system("<<<URL of the remote server>>>");
//the above command must wait for a fixed duration before coming out if no response.
```

Comment: You could use cURL insted of using system to get data from server as it provide options to set timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`timeout(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command in order to do this...

```
int status = system("timeout 60 whatever-command-you-want-to-run");
if(status != 0) {
    // Uh, oh! Either something went wrong, or the command time out after 60 seconds
}
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, you're better off with a network-oriented solution to the rather underlying problem of your situation, such as [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: Of course there’s a unix program that does this…